# Including external code on magento observer

Tags: magento

I want to include an external configuration file in a Magento Observer Model

My observer is in magento/app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodulue/Model/Observer.php  and i want to put my code in magento/scripts/examplename.php

I don't want to use a helper because this code will also be used in other scripts paced in that folder and code repetition is not a good practice

Which is the best way to do this?

Comment: So what's the problem with just `include`ing your code inside of your observer method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found to do what i was looking for is:

```
require_once BP.DS.'scripts'.DS.'examplename.php';
```

where BP and DS are Magento constants, BP=Base Path and DS= Directory Separator

Answer (score 1):

Magento is a php application and you can use `include()` and `require()` everywhere in your code however this is a bad idea to place classes and spaghetti code  inclusions in random places on your server as Magento already includes lib folder and autoloader for those if you follow the naming conventions.